# Kovan Chainlink Faucet - Unable to locate the transaction hash

Tags: chainlink, kovan, faucets

Etherscan says "Sorry, We are unable to locate this TxnHash" when sending LINK using both https://kovan.chain.link/ and https://faucets.chain.link/kovan

Waiting for a long time already but the problem persists, and no tokens are dropping to my wallet.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please use the [new chainlink and layer 1 faucet](https://faucets.chain.link/).

Comment: I was doing exactly your course =) Indeed I tried with both, but none worked.

It turns that if I send only LINK it worked, but sending both LINK and ETH was giving me the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes [etherscan](https://kovan.etherscan.io/) takes a long time to update transactions.

I just get some tokens in Chainlink Kovan [faucet](https://faucets.chain.link/) and the transaction hash `0x17347f8323e1fe486cdc4f4b44d1ab0fad64d5342a526014fbd79bec8f6677c3` didn't appear in [Etherscan](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x17347f8323e1fe486cdc4f4b44d1ab0fad64d5342a526014fbd79bec8f6677c3) yet, but it is showing in other blockchain explorers:

- [anyblocks explorer](https://explorer.anyblock.tools/ethereum/ethereum/kovan/tx/0x17347f8323e1fe486cdc4f4b44d1ab0fad64d5342a526014fbd79bec8f6677c3/)
- [ethplorer](https://kovan.ethplorer.io/tx/0x17347f8323e1fe486cdc4f4b44d1ab0fad64d5342a526014fbd79bec8f6677c3)

Answer (score 0):

At least for me, if I send only `LINK` it works.

When I tried to send both ETH and LINK then the problem happened.

Answer (score 0):

Friendly reminder re: Ethereum testnets - Kovan (and Rinkeby and Ropsten) have been deprecated. Goerli is now the main testnet. You get Goerli testETH reliably here - https://goerlifaucet.com/